# Parametric Curves Tangent Line

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, homework

Find an equation to the tangent of the curve at the given point. Then graph the curve and the tangent.

$$x=t^2-t,\quad y=t^2+t+1; \quad(0,3)$$

I can do this with a simple $f(X)$ function but the parametric curve part is tricky. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I get, but I am not sure. But please check if this is what the final solution should be as I am not too good in calculus. There are two solutions, so I picked the one which goes through `(0,3)`

```
ClearAll[x, y, t]
eq1 = x == t^2 - t;
eq2 = y == t^2 + t + 1;
r = Eliminate[{eq1, eq2}, t];
sol = y /. Solve[r, y];
slope = (D[Last@sol, x]) /. x -> 0
eq = TraditionalForm@Row[{"y(x)=", slope*x + 3}];
p1 = Plot[Callout[slope*x + 3, eq, Above], {x, -.5, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red];
p2 = Plot[sol, {x, -2, 2}, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
    GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,BaseStyle -> 14];
Show[p2, p1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

```
x[t_] = t^2 - t;
y[t_] = t^2 + t + 1;
```

The value of `t` for the point `{0, 3}` is

```
Solve[{x[t] == 0, y[t] == 3}, t][[1]]

(*  {t -> 1}  *)
```

The derivative at this point is

```
y'[t]/x'[t] /. t -> 1

(*  3  *)

Show[
 ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]},
  {t, -1, 2}],
 Plot[3 x + 3, {x, -1, 1},
  PlotStyle -> Red],
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Tangent

```
tan[f_, x_: t, scale_: 0.5] := 
 With[{df = D[f, t]}, 
  Arrow[{f, f + scale df / Norm[df]}] /. t -> x]
```

Normal

```
nor[f_, x_: t, scale_: 0.5] := 
 With[{df = D[f, t]}, 
  Arrow[{f, f + scale (df /. {a_, b_} :> {-b, a}) / Norm[df]}] /. t -> x]
```

Symbolic example

```
tan[{t, t^2}, t, 1]
```

[image]

Numeric example:

```
tan[{t, t^2}, 0.5, 1]
```

[image]

Plotting is straightforward

```
g := {t, t^2}

Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[g, {t, -1, 1},
  BaseStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Thickness[0.005]},
  Epilog -> {Orange, tan[g, n], Blue, nor[g, n], Red, Point[g /. t -> n]},
  PlotRangePadding -> 0.5],
 {n, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Or use the inbuilt `FrenetSerretSystem`

```
tan[f_, x_: t, s_: 0.5] := 
 Arrow[{f, f + s FrenetSerretSystem[f, t][[2, 1]]}] /. t -> x

nor[f_, x_: t, s_: 0.5] := 
 Arrow[{f, f + s FrenetSerretSystem[f, t][[2, 2]]}] /. t -> x
```